# google sheet change background based on text in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, cell, background-color

I am new in `google sheet` programming a macro.

I want to use a script for changing the background based on the color writen in a cell. So all the cells checked and find out what color is written.

If there is in cel `D7` the text `"green"`, the background from `D1:D7` changes into the color `green`
If there is in cel `E7` the text `"blue"`, the background from `E1:E7` changes into the color `blue`
and so one

[example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JE981G_qbtpCG9lVJYSlsKhhmaAXtijUXY9kDYIqxVQ/edit?usp=sharing)
Thanks for thinking

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use a script for changing the background based on the color writen in a cell. So all the cells checked and find out what color is written.

I know you ask for a script. You could also use though, conditional formatting rules instead.

Please use the following formulas for the range you need.

```
=REGEXMATCH(D1:D7,"green")

=REGEXMATCH(E1:E7,"blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that works but if in there ar in the sheet several colors i have to make for all the different color a rule is that correct?